# preg_replace - replaced content returns at the begining of output

Tags: php, preg-replace, create-function

I lost a lot of time because of that issue, and I'm really resigned..

When I using preg_replace with create_function , all results going at the beggining of output, but they should be in the place of founded match, just like:

> **COMPONENT1 COMPONENT2** Maecenas malesuada elit lectus felis, malesuada ultricies. Curabitur
>   et ligula. Ut molestie a, ultricies porta urna. Vestibulum commodo
>   volutpat a, convallis ac, laoreet enim. Phasellus fermentum in, dolor.
>   Pellentesque facilisis. Nulla imperdiet sit amet magna. Vestibulum
>   dapibus, mauris nec malesuada fames ac turpis velit, rhoncus eu,
>   luctus et interdum adipiscing wisi.

And should be:

> Maecenas malesuada elit lectus felis, malesuada ultricies. Curabitur
>   et ligula. Ut molestie a, ultricies porta urna. Vestibulum commodo
>   volutpat a, convallis ac, laoreet enim. Phasellus fermentum **COMPONENT1** in, dolor.
>   Pellentesque facilisis. Nulla imperdiet sit amet magna **COMPONENT2**. Vestibulum
>   dapibus, mauris nec malesuada fames ac turpis velit, rhoncus eu,
>   luctus et interdum adipiscing wisi.

```
function getcomponent($source){
   $get = getXML(datadir.$source.'.xml')->content;
   $getcomp = create_function("",' ?>'.$get.'<?php ');
   $getcomp();
}

preg_match_all("/\[\#PHP (.*?) \#\]/",$content,$content3);

foreach ($content3[1] as $value) { //$content3[0]
    $content2 = preg_replace("/\[\#PHP ".$value." \#\]/",getcomponent($value),$content);
    $content = $content2;
}
```

I will be very grateful for every tip. Cheers!

Comment: I think by simplifying your code for the example you went a bit overboard. Few questions: Why would you use create function like that and then immediately call it? What is $content? In general what are you trying to do here? It seems you are getting XML from a file, what do you want to do with it?

Comment: Hello! $content is a page content from XML file, Inside that content I have something like [# component1 #] and [# component2 #] and I want to replace it by content from component1.xml and component2.xml.  But in that component xml's I have a plain PHP code, that I want to execute, thats why I use this create_function - its a override for eval() function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your getcomponent function should return the retrieved XML instead of printing it.

```
function getcomponent($source){
    $get = getXML(datadir.$source.'.xml')->content;
    $getcomp = create_function("",' ?>'.$get.'<?php ');
    ob_start();
    $getcomp();
    return ob_get_clean();

}
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Yes, You're right, but this way I got returned plain PHP code, not evaluated by PHP

Comment: updated the answer to use output buffering to get the output in a variable and return that. If you are using a framework make sure that it is not using output buffering already.